# unobtrusive javascript pain points to beware of

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I have recently started learning [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Using JQuery its really fun.

However with this thinking of writing JavaScript code has come a real long way from traditional ways. Also adding quick onclick="fun()" is helpful sometimes and as the application grows 100% unobtrusive code "sometimes" become difficult to write. Like attaching multiple events to one DOM element and thinking which one will get executed ?

So i would like to know points that should be watched while writing unobtrusive JavaScript code to keep life easy.

Thanks,